# How to disable GitHub Actions Concurrency

Tags: github, github-actions

GitHub Actions concurrency broke my process, as we would push commits and want to prove they have all built.
But now with Concurrency, GitHub cancels builds on previous commits as soon as a new commit is pushed.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency

Is there a away to completely disable it?
Or even better, have it configurable per branch?

Comment: Can you please describe your use-case? Is this about merging PRs to the default branch? If so, perhaps look at [merge queues](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/managing-a-merge-queue)?

Comment: Workflow is to push each commit on a branch independently, one by one, such that CI builds each one. This now cancels each previous push.

Answer (score 2):

As [documented](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency) "Any previously pending in the concurrency group will be canceled". In others words, the queue is limited in one. Somewhat useless. To permit parallel execution just not use 'concurrency' term on action.

Comment: UPDATE: The action ahmadnassri/action-workflow-queue permit simulate a queue because forces waiting for olders running actions to finish, that guarantee running in start order. It's brilliant but increase your costs because actions wait but is running to be billed.